# Xcode 8 beta 6 swift 3 localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare

Tags: xcode, swift3, xcode8-beta6

This code was compiling on Xcode 8 beta 5 but broken in beta 6.  What is the right new Swift 3 way to do this comparison?

```
self.categories = categories.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending }
```

The error is

> Argument passes to call that takes no arguments

Comment: Might want to file a bug on bugs.swift.org if the error message is really this bad. Does it point at which call it's talking about?

Comment: The code works for me, but also the docs recommend using sorted(by: <) to sort descending.

Comment: you can use `sort` without `ed` in Swift 3 to sort in place. `categories.sort { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == .orderedDescending }`

Comment: sorted(by: <) gives me the same error.

Comment: I've updated the code above with more context

Comment: The problem is self.categories was an NSArray?.  I thought the issue was with the sort command because it discussed arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I just have succeeded to get the same error message.

In my testing code, if I declare the instance property `categories` as:

```
var categories: [NSString] = []
```

I have got this error message:

> error: argument passed to call that takes no arguments

If your case is very similar to this, you need to change the property declaration to:

```
var categories: [String] = []
```

Even if this does not fit for your issue, you'd better check this sort of type-mismatching, because as of Swift 3/Xcode 8 beta 6:

> - Bridging conversions are no longer implicit. The conversion from a Swift value type to its corresponding object can be forced with `as`.
>     For example: `string as NSString`. Any Swift value can also be
>     converted to its boxed `id` representation with `as AnyObject`.
>     (SE-0072)

(Taken from the Release Notes of Xcode 8 beta 6.)

Comment: The problem is self.categories was an NSArray?. I thought the issue was with the sort command because it discussed arguments.

Comment: @JasonHocker, Swift 3 is evolving so swift that Swift team have no time to refine its diagnostic messages. When Swift cannot find a matching overload of `sorted` which returns an expected type (in your case `NSArray`?), it sometimes output this sort of inadequate and confusing message. And I think this sort of bad diagnostics should be considered as bug, and you'd better send a bug report to Apple or swift.org.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here. I tried to compile a snippet from the official Swift 3 guide in Xcode beta and got the same error - `Argument passes to call that takes no arguments`. Though, when I used IBM Swift Sandbox, it compiled successfully.

```
let names = ["Chris", "Alex", "Ewa", "Barry", "Daniella"]
func backward(_ s1: String, _ s2: String) -> Bool {
return s1 > s2
}
var reversedNames = names.sorted(by: backward)
```

From looking [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/fa75ca35911a8d20f5f38d0f19e3ab38457b4ab9/proposals/0118-closure-parameter-names-and-labels.md), it seems that the API of sorted changed from 
x.sorted(isOrderedBefore: >) to x.sorted(by: >). I guess that in the future Xcode beta, this will be taken care of.

Comment: another way of writing that:
var reversedNames = names.sorted(by: {s1, s2 -> Bool in s1 > s2 })